# How can I make a bootable USB copy of Mojave downloaded from Apple when the file is an app and not a disk image?

Tags: mojave, big-sur, bootable-disk

When I try to open the Mojave install app on my computer with Big Sur, it says that the operating system is too old and so it will not let me open it in order to install it on the external usb drive.

Additionally, the alternative method - restoring Mojave onto the external drive is not possible because the Mojave install file is an app and not a disk image.

How can I proceed to create a bootable copy of Mojave on my external USB drive considering I am on a computer with Big Sur and the Mojave download is an app file which will not open and it is not a DMG file which I would otherwise be able to restore onto the external USB?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the `createinstallmedia` directions here: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

For the sake of completeness, here’s the command you would run in *Terminal* to create the install media for Mojave (it’s slightly different for each OS version):

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

Comment: Ok, it almost worked, I now have USB key that shows "Install macOS Mojave" but when I boot my laptop while holding the 'option' key, only the original laptop volume appears as bootable.

Comment: Did you reformat the drive as an HFS+ (Mac OS Extended) volume before running the `createinstallmedia` command?

Comment: Mac OS extended journaled w/ guid partition map scheme

Comment: What model & year is your computer?

Comment: 2017, 12 inch macbook

Comment: Oh some addition steps, 1 reset pram. 2 have to press and hold the option key again after it shows you the first volume when the selector screen appears, and the other volume will appear. 3. Select the installer to boot from 4. Install it to another USB drive that you then plug in

Comment: Im trying this but im on battery power so have to wait for a full charge

Comment: I do believe that the createinstallmedia command actually formats the target volume correctly for that OS version. You could look at it with disk utility and see if there are "extra" partitions that might be preventing it from being a boot volume. It is odd that it was not bootable, do you have another flash drive to test with?